# laravel 5.6 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] connection refused on freash install

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homestead

I'm trying to setup a new laravel 5.6 project and I'm currently having issues with getting the database migrated. I've fiddled with the hosts names from localhost to 127.etc and the box IP. After creatingthe auth blades I can't create a new user I receive a 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] connection refused error.
I have attempted to log into the box to see what's in the database but I get the same error when I connect with the default homestead U&P. I also tried root/root but received the same error.

Here is part DB config

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

'redis' => [

```
    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
```

Comment: Check up codecourse how to install laravel on homestead or even laracast.

Comment: What you do mean box ip ? Your local ip ?

Comment: Could you check it manually via mysql tool with the same config?

Comment: Sulthan Allaudeen: I'm using homestead which uses vagrant box to run the server stuff I need to run laravel. so the ip is the VMBox IP no my machine ip. Localhost 127.etc should work fine since the files are being loaded on the VMbox

Comment: Check what manually vuong? I've logged into the mysql and poked around the tables. Seems the homestead user name is there twice (not sure how that happens) with the same password. My table is empty which is what I think its causing some of the error but when I've tried to fill it with other commands I've found I get a PDO error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sshing into the homestead vagrant box and running 'artisan migrate:install' which solved the bulk of my problems. I then had to create a database schema partially generated by laravel and the rest edited by myself.

Answer (score 0):

try it : `'strict' => true,` To `strict' => false,` in  DB config Part

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I even copied and pasted my database over from another project that works and no luck, I don't think the problem is with the config file.